# Is it Possible to Open a Visual Basic for Devices Project in Studio 2010 or 2013?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm evaluating source code that was created in either Studio 2005 or 2008.  The solution contains a Visual Basic for Devices project .vbdbproj.  I tried to open/convert it in Studio 2010 but could not do so.  Since I don't have Studio 2005 or 2008 installed, how can I used either Studio 2010 or 2013 to open this solution?

Comment: Studio 2010 uses Net 4.0 while Studio 2013 uses Net 4.5.  The best solution is to compile in 2010 with Net 4.0 or set 2013 properties for Net 4.0.

Comment: Windows Mobile/CE was fatally struck by an apple in 2008 and support for mobile projects was discontinued in 2010.  You must have VS2008, no other way around that.  Get an MSDN subscription, always the best way.